# Lookup field not accessible

Tags: lookup, angularjs

We are using angular to display UI and Salesforce is being used to maintain database. We have a REST API class created which has the url Mapping. This class is used to find the records.

We are using '`Customer Community Login`' Custom profile and need to check the data by logging as Community User.

We have a lookup field in a custom object (`Customer__c`). This object and the lookup field (`Book__c`) are being queried in angular. The required lookup field already have 'Read' access on the Custom profile. However, this lookup field is not running on front-end. Its getting a 'null' response. We checked all the possible IDs and fields access, permission sets, triggers but none seems to be blocking it from getting it accessible from font-end. The OWD for the related object (`Book__c`, being used in lookup field) is 'Controlled by Parent' and we cannot change it to Public Read/Write.

Below is the query- `SELECT Book__r.No_of_Users__c, Name FROM Customer__c`

When accessing the Book__c directly, it is displaying te required result but is giving null response when accessing Book's No_of_Users__c field.

Please suggest what could be cause of this blockage.

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: @Programatic Ive edited my question and added the code. Here No_of_Users__c is not accessible

Comment: Since the accessibility is controlled by the parent, does the parent(master relatonship) have public read/write?

Comment: Not, it is Private

Comment: That's probably the issue